# Will session unification work with multi channel funnels in Google Analytics?

Tags: session, google-analytics, userid, universal-analytics

I'm looking at implementing [User Id](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en) for google analytics. It's basically a way to tell Google Analytics if a logged in user is the same, even if they come from different devices.

Google says that if i'm logged in as a anonymous user and then provide a user ID, it will merge the current, anonymous session and add the data to the identfied session, does this mean that multi-channel-funnels will include visits from before the user got authed?

Answer (score 0):

Google cannot attribute old sessions with this new user id. all it would do is to integrate the existing session data with the User id generated in the current session